# How to get transferable docker compose stack without dockerhub

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I have few docker images composed together in the stack using docker-compose.yml.

Now I want to transfer whole docker compose stack to the other host machine without uploading to the dockerhub,
And deploy it on the docker swarm.

I saw there is a thing called docker compose bundle, would that help?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re deploying on a multi-host swarm (or something similar like Kubernetes or Nomad) you all but need a Docker registry.  It doesn’t specifically have to be Docker Hub — quay.io, Amazon’s ECR, Google’s GCR, and self-hosted registries all work fine — but you do need to have pushed the built images *somewhere* where the orchestrator can retrieve them by name.

I’ve never used `docker-compose bundle` myself, but [its documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/bundle/) also notes that its operation “requires interaction with a Docker registry”.

The only real alternative is using `docker save` and `docker load` to manually move images between machines, but as a manual process it will get tedious very quickly, and you need to make sure an identical set of images are on every machine for consistency.  Using a registry will be vastly easier.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way to do it is to use a Docker registry. The problem with Docker Hub is that you can only have one private registry, the rest must be public or paid.

Thankfully, there are other (free) alternatives:

1. Deploy your own private registry. Here is a nice [tutorial](https://www.katacoda.com/courses/docker-production/launch-private-registry) where you can try it in the browser.
2. Use a free private registry. I personnaly use [Codefresh](https://codefresh.io/). It can automatically build your image from a private repo (like [bitbucket](https://codefresh.io/) who has free plan too), but you can also just [use it like a "simple" docker registry](https://codefresh.io/docs/docs/docker-registries/codefresh-registry/#use-codefresh-registry-locally) and push and pull your Docker images there.